# Login to a page which is a hyperlink from a href

Tags: web, authentication, hyperlink, href, automatic-updates

I would like to code for auto login to a form from a Java exe that will allow me to follow a `href` link which will re-direct to another site whereby this site will have a login which I will then supply the credentials and then download the contents of the page and then enter details into the page and submit it.

Will that sounds a tall order for a Java coding? Usually this process is done by a human operator but I need to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

1.- Prepare a Sniffer like HttpFox Firefox add-on or Whireshark.

2.- Do login in the site and take the url of the login, the method ( GET or POST ) and the parameters name for username and password ( You may also get this from the source code of the login page ).

3.- Navigate into the site and take de name of the session cookies ( or from all the cookies ).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class Tests {

    public static String cookie;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        URL url = new URL("https://some_site...");
        HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        https.setRequestMethod( "POST" ); //or GET
        https.addRequestProperty( "usename_field_name", "username" );
        https.addRequestProperty( "password_field_name", "password" );
        https.addRequestProperty( "Cookie", cookie );

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(https.getInputStream()));

        String linea;

        while ((linea = in.readLine()) != null) {
            // Recover the cookie and save it in a variable.
            // You must put it in other connections.
        }
    }
}
```